# Laravel 5.4 using Mail fake with Mail::queue, Mail::assertSent not working

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, email, laravel-5

I am writing unit test for a code that sends email with Mail::queue function, like the one in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking#mail-fake

**My Test:**

```
/** @test */
public function send_reminder()
{
     Mail::fake();

     $response = $this->actingAs($this->existing_account)->json('POST', '/timeline-send-reminder', []);
     $response->assertStatus(302);

     Mail::assertSent(ClientEmail::class, function ($mail) use ($approver) {
          return $mail->approver->id === $approver->id;
     });
}
```

**Code being Tested:**

```
Mail::to($email, $name)->queue(new ClientEmail(Auth::user()));
```

**Error Message:**

```
The expected [App\Mail\ClientEmail] mailable was not sent.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

The email is sent when I manually test it, but not from Unit Test. I'm thinking it might be because I am using `Mail::queue` instead of `Mail::send` function.

In `.env` file, I have

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync and MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

How can I test `Mail::queue` for Laravel?

Comment: Have you tried`QUEUE_DRIVER=database`? This worked when I tested it.

Comment: What is an `approver` property? Looks like it is an entity and you should compare `approver->id` rather that `approver`.

Comment: Thanks @shukshin.ivan, I've fixed it, it should be approver->id. The problem is still there. It still doesn't recognize that the email was sent.

Comment: @AanFaisal I've tried it, it doesn't make a difference

Comment: First, simply test using `Mail::queue('your_blade_file', $data, function ($message) {
    // Some code here...
});`

Comment: @SeyongCho Have you test using my comment??

Comment: @HirenGohel I'm not sure what you mean by test using Mail::queue. It sends the email, but just the Mail fake isn't catching that it has sent...

Comment: Use `// Assert a message was sent to the given users...
        Mail::assertSentTo([$user], ClientEmail::class);` after `Mail::assertSent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

The problem was that the class was not imported at the top of PHPUnit test file.

Importing the mail class solved the issue. Strange how it didn't error out the testcase itself.